# How to pass buffer/binary file to Bull Queue in NestJS/Node?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multer, bull-queue

I want to pass buffer of a file uploaded (which can be large - 100MB) which i input as form data to Bull Queue, but bull Queue doesnt accept binary or buffer.

How can I pass it?

I can change multer destination to /tmp and try to read from that location in Bull Queue Task Processor, but /tmp files might be deleted before processing